# Does anybody know a gem/plugin for private messages in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, private-messaging

Does anybody know of a gem or plugin for Rails3 that allows for sending Private Messages between users of a site? I'm using Devise for my authentication.

I've stumbled upon [simple-private-messages](https://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages), which is one possibility, but that's about it (other plugins/gems that I found are very outdated). Does anybody know if any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few out there, such as acts_as_messageable and has_messages.

If you really want to use a plugin, acts_as_messageable is great if it does what you want, but chances are it would better if you wrote one yourself - it sounds like you want quite a specific solution that probably doesn't have a plugin that would fit exactly in.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up rolling out my own. Very simple and fun to do :)

Comment: also, what an awesome 16 year old who knows rails! when I was your age (hehe 4 years ago) I only knew PHP. ugh.

Answer (score 0):

We are searching for a solution ourselves.. most promising and new is the mailboxer gem. Very active development, good documentation ..

https://github.com/ging/mailboxer

if we decide to use it, i will come back to write more about it.

and more about it here as well: [Anyone knows good private message gem for rails 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113132/anyone-knows-good-private-message-gem-for-rails-3-2)